# how to make count similar id object in list and display in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON array, in that I need to make match count using ParentCommentID and parse data into recyclerview using text view while  counting  i get number count only one position and same for other item also, any help.

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "e7433825-6771-4f5e-96c7-c4d2674d7764",
          "uri": "",
          "etag": "\"2\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.InquiryDiscussionsListListItem"
        },
        "Author": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "f064775c-6161-4bdb-9f4d-8bc6a898d218",
            "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
          },
          "Title": "Submitter1"
        },
        "Id": 1501,
        "ID": 1501,
        "Title": null,
        "Created": "2019-06-06T04:15:17Z",
        "ParentCommentID": "1439",
        "Comment": "<div class=\"ExternalClass8C333A77B6564A53BED74CA1BA2D2A10\">
        reply add for 009</div>",
        "CommentType": null,
        "CommentDocumentName": null,
        "AppID": "1083",
        "Role": "Customer"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "e92f708f-93dc-4587-8c4f-5518ed24f360",
          "uri": "",
          "etag": "\"2\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.InquiryDiscussionsListListItem"
        },
        "Author": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "209d2d9a-bb07-4064-aaa0-231ad881a80f",
            "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
          },
          "Title": "Submitter1"
        },
        "Id": 1500,
        "ID": 1500,
        "Title": null,
        "Created": "2019-06-06T04:14:55Z",
        "ParentCommentID": "1439",
        "Comment": "<div class=\"ExternalClass44B1A0BB4D314C57BEE20141BFF10491\">comment add for       009</div>",
        "CommentType": null,
        "CommentDocumentName": null,
        "AppID": "1083",
        "Role": "Customer"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "ec112002-3132-4bc1-8f85-03fbd9fda11d",
          "uri": "",
          "etag": "\"2\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.InquiryDiscussionsListListItem"
        },
        "Author": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "6e8ecb1d-4deb-4168-a8b4-a725abf8002a",
            "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
          },
          "Title": "Sarada Devi Potti"
        },
        "Id": 1439,
        "ID": 1439,
        "Title": "Canceled",
        "Created": "2019-06-03T09:32:34Z",
        "ParentCommentID": null,
        "Comment": "<div  class=\"ExternalClass5E1BFEDC348C43719AD940E644E0E0B6\">sdaeadfasdf</div>",
        "CommentType": "Public",
        "CommentDocumentName": null,
        "AppID": "1083",
        "Role": "Budget Analyst"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My code is onbind method:

```
 Map<String, Integer> commentsCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Result res : discussionsList) {
        String parentCommentId = res.getParentCommentID();
        // If the MyDocsResult has a parent comment
        if(parentCommentId != null) {
            // get the count for this parent comment (default to 0)
            int nbCommentsForParent = commentsCountMap.getOrDefault(parentCommentId, 0);
            // increment the count
            nbCommentsForParent++;
            // Update the Map with the new count
            commentsCountMap.put(parentCommentId, nbCommentsForParent);
            System.out.println(commentsCountMap);
            Log.d("Count:",commentsCountMap.toString());


        }
    }
```

for example id `1439`, having two `ParentCommentID`, so in that case for id `1439` there should be a count of two comments, I tried to use for in my 
 recyclerview adapter but its dose not work.

Comment: what are you trying to map in for loop.?

Comment: @HemantParmar I trid to cound number of parantCommentid using id I compare number of parantCommentid if  count is simile is ID I just want  to parse that count in textview for that ID.

Comment: Looks like you would need to have your list of Result in the method to look through the list and find the comments that have 1439 as a ParentCommentID. Is discussionsList the list of all the Results?

Comment: @Bentaye yes that why I took hash map to store all match result but its does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to run through the list of Results and when when you find a Result that has a parent comment, then you go in the map, get the parent comment, increment its count by one and stick it back in the Map:

Assuming your Result class is something like this:

```
class Result {
    private String id;
    private String parentCommentID;

    public Result(String id, String parentCommentID) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentCommentID = parentCommentID;
    }

    // GETTERS/SETTERS
}
```

And you have a discussion list with 3 Results

```
    discussionsList = Arrays.asList(
        new Result("1439", null),
        new Result("1500", "1439"),
        new Result("1801", "1439")
    );
```

Like your case, 1439 has no parent and 1500 and 1501 both have 1439 as parent

Then you can do this kind of thing:

```
Map<String, Integer> commentsCountMap = new HashMap<>();
// Loop through the discussion Map
for(Result res : discussionsList) {
    String parentCommentId = res.getParentCommentID();
    // If the Result has a parent comment
    if(parentCommentId != null) {
        // get the count for this parent comment (default to 0)
        int nbCommentsForParent = commentsCountMap.getOrDefault(parentCommentId, 0);
        // increment the count
        nbCommentsForParent++;
        // Update the Map with the new count
        commentsCountMap.put(parentCommentId, nbCommentsForParent);
    }
}

System.out.println(commentsCountMap);
```

This outputs

```
{1439=2}
```

Comment: I have one dought here can we add extra array for same layout view?

Comment: sorry, I do not know how layout views work, I can only help with the counting algorithm